# Missing parenthesis when using macros in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am getting a 'bad suffix on number' and a missing parenthesis at the last printf.
Do you have any idea why this is not working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define suma(a, b) a + b
#define alipire(a,b) a##b
int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3, maxim;
    maxim = a > b ? a : b;
    printf("%d \n",suma(a, b)*5);
    printf("%d", alipire(suma(a, b), maxim));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After macro expansion, your two `printf` statements become `printf("%d \n",a + b*5);` and    `printf("%d", a + b maxim);`  It's not entriely clear to me what you intended.

Comment: How does token concatenation make the slightest sense here?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

When the macro `suma(a, b)` is replaced in `printf("%d \n",suma(a, b)*5);`, the result is `printf("%d \n",a + b *5);`, which may not be what you want as it multiplies `b` by `5` before adding `a`.

When `alipire(suma(a, b), maxim)` is replaced, the steps are:

- `alipire` is initially replaced by `suma ( a , b ) ## maximum`. I inserted spaces to emphasize the organization into preprocessor tokens.
- The `##` is processed to concatenate tokens. This would form `suma ( a, b )maximum`. However, `)maximum` is not a valid preprocessor token. Per the rule in C 2018 6.10.3.3 3, the behavior is not defined.

Attempting to reproduce the problem with various major compilers, include MSVC, on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KK6PeM) yielded various error messages but not “bad suffix on number”. Perhaps you are using an older version of Visual Studio or the source code that produced that error was different from the source code shown in the question. So specific analysis for that error message cannot be done without more information, such as the specific compiler version and command-line switches used.

Comment: Firstly, the sum was ok, I wanted to see what the order of the operations would be. Secondly, regarding the concatenation,  I just wanted to see if macros do work like functions( one in another). So I tried doing a concatenation between the sum and the maximum. So should I declare a variable for the sum and the concatenate it with the maximum or should I declare variables for both of them? I just dont know why the program doesn't do the sum first and then concatenate it with the maximum.

Comment: @BENTAMARIUS: We do not know what you are trying to do. “Concatenate it with the maximum” does not make sense. Show examples.

Comment: lets say a is 2 and b is 3 for example, suma(a,b)*5 should be 17 . suma (a,b) should be 5( it's 2+3). Also the maximum should be 3 ( beacuse 3>2). So the alipire( suma(a,b), maxim) should be alipire(5,3) so it should be 53 as an int. Still the concatenation does not work

Comment: Concatenation in preprocessor macros can only change the source code; it cannot concatenate run-times. To concatenate two values in the program output, simply print them with no space between them, as with `printf("%d%d", suma(a, b), maxim);`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot eric! now I do understand better how the concatenation works in macros.